# How to add a horizontal line at a specific point in chart.js when hovering?

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js, dom-events

I want to be able to add multiple points as a reference place where I can show the horizontal line.

Here is an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: img]

I want to also make it so that when you don't hover over a point its opacity gets reduced and  when you hover over it the opacity is normal. I'm also not sure how to add the square and make the square bigger when hovered hover and it adds the 'wow' text. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [chart.js annotations plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) to draw horizontal lines at specific values, then you can implement a proper `onHover` callback (events on the whole chart) to show/hide those lines.

```
annotation : {
    drawTime : "afterDraw",
    annotations : [{
            id : "line1",
            type : "line",
            mode : "horizontal",
            scaleID : "y-axis",
            value : 4.5,
            borderWidth : 2,
            borderColor : "red",
            label : {
                content : "threshold 1",
                enabled : true,
                position : "right"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

See my fiddle exemplifying the approach: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/5jg4wgdh/

```js
var data_set = [{x: 1, y: 12}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 8}, {x: 6, y: 8}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 2}, {x: 9, y: 3}, {x: 10, y: 5}, {x: 11, y: 11}, {x: 12, y: 1}];
var labels = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

var lines = [], id = 0;
var linesOn = false;

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: data_set,
  }]
};

var option = {
  legend: false,
  title: {
    display: true,
  },
  onHover: function(evt) {
   console.log("onHover", evt.type);
    if (evt.type == 'mousemove' && linesOn == false) {
     linesOn = true;
      myLineChart.options.annotation.annotations = lines;
      myLineChart.update();
    } else if (evt.type == 'mouseout' && linesOn == true) {
     linesOn = false;
     myLineChart.options.annotation.annotations = [];
     myLineChart.update();
    }
    var item = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    if (item.length) {
      console.log(">item", item);
      console.log(">data", item[0]._index, data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]);
    }
  },
  onClick: function(evt) {
    var el = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    console.log("onClick", el, evt);
  },
  annotation: {
    drawTime: "afterDraw",
    annotations: lines
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      id: 'x-axis',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: 12,
        min: 1,
        stepSize: 1,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return data.labels[index];
        }
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis',
      type: 'linear',
    }],
  }

};

var myLineChart = Chart.Line('myChart', {
  data: data,
  options: option
});

// define two lines (these code must be after chart creation)
addLine(3.5);
addLine(7);

function addLine(value) {
  id++;
  var ln = {
    id: "line" + id,
    type: "line",
    mode: "horizontal",
    scaleID: "y-axis",
    value: value,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "red",
    label: {
      content: "threshold " + id,
      enabled: true,
      position: "right"
    }
  };
  lines.push(ln);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

**Update:**

If you need to animate annotation hovering on them, here is another example:

https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/yxy402rk/

```js
var data_set = [{x: 1, y: 12}, {x: 2, y: 3}, {x: 3, y: 2}, {x: 4, y: 1}, {x: 5, y: 8}, {x: 6, y: 8}, {x: 7, y: 2}, {x: 8, y: 2}, {x: 9, y: 3}, {x: 10, y: 5}, {x: 11, y: 11}, {x: 12, y: 1}];
var labels = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

var lines = [], id = 0;
var linesOn = false;

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: data_set,
  }]
};

var option = {
  legend: false,
  title: {
    display: true,
  },
  onHover: function(evt) {
    var item = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    if (item.length) {
      console.log(">item", item);
      console.log(">data", item[0]._index, data.datasets[0].data[item[0]._index]);
    }
  },
  onClick: function(evt) {
    var el = myLineChart.getElementAtEvent(evt);
    console.log("onClick", el, evt);
  },
  annotation: {
    drawTime: "afterDraw",
    events: ['click','mouseenter','mouseleave'],
    annotations: lines
  },
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      id: 'x-axis',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'bottom',
      ticks: {
        max: 12,
        min: 1,
        stepSize: 1,
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return data.labels[index];
        }
      }
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      id: 'y-axis',
      type: 'linear',
    }],
  }

};

addLine(3.5);
addLine(7);

var myLineChart = Chart.Line('myChart', {
  data: data,
  options: option
});

console.log(myLineChart.annotation.elements.line1);
myLineChart.annotation.elements.line1.hidden = true;
myLineChart.update();

function addLine(value) {
  id++;
  var ln = {
    id: "line" + id,
    type: "line",
    mode: "horizontal",
    scaleID: "y-axis",
    value: value,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "rgba(0,0,255,0.3)",
    label: {
      content: "threshold " + id,
      enabled: true,
      position: "right",
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
    },
    onMouseenter: function(e) {
     console.log("onMouseenter", e, this);
      this.options.borderColor = "rgba(0,0,255,0.8)";
      this.options.label.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)';
      myLineChart.update();
    },
    onMouseleave: function(e) {
     console.log("onMouseleave", e);
      this.options.borderColor = "rgba(0,0,255,0.3)";
      this.options.label.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
      myLineChart.update();
    },
  };
  lines.push(ln);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/0.5.7/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: The updated answer is exactly what I needed, thank you so much. Now i can work with this :)

Comment: I want to add `shadowBlur: 10` and `shadowColor: "black"` to the horizontal lines, do you know how to do this?

Comment: No, those CSS properties are not supported by chartjs-plugin-annotation, see https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation

Comment: What is the best way to implement this feature? @beaver

Comment: You could fork the github project and modify the `draw()` function of `line` class: see https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/blob/master/src/types/line.js#L124