# chart.js how to fill from a line to the max or min of the y-axis

Tags: chart.js

I have a bootstrap modal that shows a plot of xy data between a max and min tolerance range. To show tolerances lines, I create two datasets for the min (30) and max (70) horizontal lines. To highlight the tolerance area, I create another two lines at the yAxes max and min plot range values. The issue I have is that when I use `chart.scales['y-axis-0']` to get the yAxes range the values are not correctly updated. They just appear as 0 and 100. Strangely if I close and then reopen the modal the ranges are then correct. It seems that chartjs does an automatic calculation of the yAxes range, however, I am not able to get access to it. Is there a way to get access to the yAxes ranges just before the plot is drawn? Or, is there a better way to solve this problem than creating two lines at the top and bottom of the plot and filling up or down to them...?

```
var y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];
var y_tol_max = new Array(y.length).fill(70);
var y_tol_min = new Array(y.length).fill(30);
var y_axis_max = new Array(y.length).fill(y_axis.max);
var y_axis_min = new Array(y.length).fill(y_axis.min);

chart.data.datasets.push({ borderColor: '#ffe6e6', data: y_axis_max, fill: false, radius: 0 });
chart.data.datasets.push({ borderColor: '#ffe6e6', backgroundColor: '#ffe6e6', data:  y_tol_max, fill: '-1', label: 'Danger', radius: 0 });
```

Comment: have you checked annotations plugin? See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506282/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-at-a-specific-point-in-chart-js-when-hovering

Comment: @beaver Would your annotations plugin allow fill from the horizontal line to the max or min of the y-axis?

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/yxy402rk/. It has xAxes timeline, but it can be any linear xAxes

Comment: if you share a complete sample of your code (like a fiddle) I can add annotations to it