# ChartJS Annotation Hide /Show

Tags: charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am using an annotation plugin to draw the horizontal line in my chart. Is there any way to hide & show annotation based on condition?

my code:

```
annotation: {

   drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
   annotations: [{
      id: 'hline1',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: 50,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderDash: [8,5],
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
       backgroundColor: "red",
         content: "Benchmark",
         enabled: true,
          position : "left"
      }
   }, {
      id: 'hline2',
      type: 'line',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: 30,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderDash: [8,5],
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
        backgroundColor: "green",
         content: "Target",
         enabled: true,
          position : "left"
      }
   }]

},
```

Comment: An example of showing/hiding annotations is in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506282/how-to-add-a-horizontal-line-at-a-specific-point-in-chart-js-when-hovering/48517143#48517143

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to update the chart by switching drawtime from "afterDatasetsDraw" to null, based on your desired condition.

Something like:

```
function toggleAnnotation(chart) {
    if (chart.options.annotation.drawTime == "afterDatasetsDraw"){
        chart.options.annotation.drawTime = null;
     } else {
        chart.options.annotation.drawTime = "afterDatasetsDraw";
     }
     chart.update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best answer but since Chartjs Annotation Plugin doesn't allow to show or hide annotations you can simple leave the annotation type blank and that will hide tha annotation.

then based on your condition you can add the type back again.

```
annotation: {

   drawTime: 'afterDatasetsDraw',
   annotations: [{
      id: 'hline1',
      type: '',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: 50,
      borderColor: 'red',
      borderDash: [8,5],
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
       backgroundColor: "red",
         content: "Benchmark",
         enabled: true,
          position : "left"
      }
   }, {
      id: 'hline2',
      type: '',
      mode: 'horizontal',
      scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
      value: 30,
      borderColor: 'green',
      borderDash: [8,5],
      borderWidth: 1,
      label: {
        backgroundColor: "green",
         content: "Target",
         enabled: true,
          position : "left"
      }
   }]

},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function UnDraw() {
        window.myLine.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
            window.myLine.options.annotation.annotations.pop();
        });
        window.myLine.update();
    };
    function Draw(a) {
        window.myLine.options.annotation.annotations.push(
            {
                type: 'box',
                drawTime: 'afterDraw',
                xScaleID: 'x-axis-0',
                yScaleID: 'y-axis-0',
                xMax: a * 1000,
                xMin: a * 1000,
                yMax: MAXY,
                yMin: MINY,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,102,0,1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,102,0,1)',
            });
        window.myLine.update();
    };
```